# How to close google glass Application

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

How can I get back to the Google glass main menu inside my application, I have tried using `finish()` , `close()` , `system.exit()` , but nothing is working,

My application is voice command, so when I'm done I want to go to main menu.

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this line `this.finishAffinity();`

Finish this activity as well as all activities immediately below it in the current task that have the same affinity. This is typically used when an application can be launched on to another task (such as from an ACTION_VIEW of a content type it understands) and the user has used the up navigation to switch out of the current task and in to its own task. In this case, if the user has navigated down into any other activities of the second application, all of those should be removed from the original task as part of the task switch.

Note that this finish does not allow you to deliver results to the previous activity, and an exception will be thrown if you are trying to do so.